# Django Rest Framework relation Attribute error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm fighting to find my way into DRF and can't get related data into my endpoint.

models.py

```
class ChapterMark(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    episode         = models.ForeignKey(Episode, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_time      = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Episode(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    show            = models.ForeignKey(Show, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

serializers.py

```
class ChapterMarkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ChapterMark
        exclude = ('')

class EpisodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    chapters = ChapterMarkSerializer(source='id')

    class Meta:
        model = Episode
        depth = 1
```

The error I'm getting is

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field
>   `start_time` on serializer `ChapterMarkSerializer`. The serializer
>   field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on
>   the `int` instance. Original exception text was: 'int' object has no
>   attribute 'start_time'.

My guess is that the relation via `source='id'` just doesn't work but everything I found so far is pointing back to doing it that way.

There's a many to one relationship between chapters and episodes (so each episode has many chapters). I'm sure I'm just missing an important part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get reverse relation object use `chaptermark_set` as source of chapters field, also dont forget to add `many=True` since episode can have miltiple chapters:

```
class EpisodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    chapters = ChapterMarkSerializer(source='chaptermark_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Episode
        depth = 1
```

Comment: awesome, thanks. I had `many=True`in there before but got confused by other errors and took it out. Works now.